# Starting Angular app exceeds 512MB and crashes

Tags: heroku

I tried to deploy an Angular app inside Docker but failed to start it :

```
2021-12-19T13:12:05.766168+00:00 app[angular.1]: Compiling @angular/material/paginator : es2015 as esm2015
2021-12-19T13:12:07.703222+00:00 app[angular.1]: Compiling @angular/material/chips : es2015 as esm2015
2021-12-19T13:12:07.726244+00:00 app[angular.1]: Compiling @angular/material/badge : es2015 as esm2015
2021-12-19T13:12:08.747145+00:00 app[angular.1]: Compiling @angular/material/table : es2015 as esm2015
2021-12-19T13:12:08.799065+00:00 heroku[angular.1]: Process running mem=778M(151.5%)
2021-12-19T13:12:08.831354+00:00 heroku[angular.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2021-12-19T13:12:09.614878+00:00 app[angular.1]: Compiling @angular/material/divider : es2015 as esm2015
2021-12-19T13:12:10.652232+00:00 app[angular.1]: Compiling @angular/material/snack-bar : es2015 as esm2015
2021-12-19T13:12:11.723629+00:00 app[angular.1]: Compiling @angular/material/autocomplete : es2015 as esm2015
2021-12-19T13:12:11.731124+00:00 app[angular.1]: Compiling @angular/material/checkbox : es2015 as esm2015
2021-12-19T13:12:58.300999+00:00 heroku[angular.1]: Process running mem=750M(146.5%)
2021-12-19T13:12:58.304598+00:00 heroku[angular.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2021-12-19T13:13:21.814944+00:00 heroku[angular.1]: Process running mem=951M(185.8%)
2021-12-19T13:13:21.820760+00:00 heroku[angular.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2021-12-19T13:13:39.269766+00:00 heroku[angular.1]: Process running mem=1279M(250.0%)
2021-12-19T13:13:39.360959+00:00 heroku[angular.1]: Error R15 (Memory quota vastly exceeded)
2021-12-19T13:13:39.369783+00:00 heroku[angular.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2021-12-19T13:13:39.754136+00:00 heroku[angular.1]: Process exited with status 137
2021-12-19T13:13:39.838667+00:00 heroku[angular.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

Is there a solution other than ugrading to a $250/month (2.5 GB) plan?

UPDATE : my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14.15.0-alpine3.12

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . ./

EXPOSE 4200

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

UPDATE 2: Here's my package.json
I use nodemon because I couldn't manage to make Angular rebuild the app hosted in Docker when modifications occur.

```
     ...
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "nodemon --exec \"ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --poll 1\"",
    "build": "ng build",
    ...
```

Comment: Why is anything compiling at runtime in the first place? Shouldn't your app just be static files by this point? Please provide more information about how you are deploying. Your `Dockerfile` would be a good place to start.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question.
I used this Dockerfile to test my app in local env with docker-compose.
Should i have another Dockerfile to deploy in production? Or maybe just drop Docker...

Comment: Thanks! What is your start script? Please add your `package.json` as well.